# Merge UITableView and CollectionView in one View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to create  UI like iOS 10 Music app , which is both `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` are merge in one view and users are able to scroll it :

[image]

The way I am doing it is I added a scroll view and then added table view and collection view to it , but it doesn't work well on all devices ! for example in iPhone 7 Plus the UITableView's scroll interrupts the UIScrollView. What is the correct way to do so ?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you adding the scroll view if you are using table view ?

Comment: @BhupatBheda To add UICollectionView and merge together

Comment: That could all be one table view which has a cell that contains a collection view.

Comment: you can make Main tableview and then add new tableview to first row and add new collectionview to second row.

Comment: Take `tableview` and add `collectionview` to its cells. It's a much easier approach to achieve your goal.

Comment: @iPeter Thanks I'll do it

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem little time ago.

I ended up using 2 **container views** that each segue with an "embed segue" to another 2 VC. 
Everything is displayed on the same view, although you can benefit to a good decoupling (having the table in a viewcontroller and the collection in another).

[image]

Implement `prepare:for segue` in the mainVC, where you can inject the data needed in collection or in table.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let identifier = segue.identifier else { return }

    switch identifier {
    case "calendarVC":
        if let calendarVC = segue.destination as? CalendarVC {
            calendarVC.dataProvider = dataProvider
            self.calendarVC = calendarVC
        }
    case "eventsVC":
        if let eventsVC = segue.destination as? EventsVC {
            self.eventsVC = eventsVC
            eventsVC.dataProvider = dataProvider
        }
    default: break
    }
}
```

You can see that I have all on a single screen:

[image]

Comment: I've used it successfully! If data from table depends on the collection and so on, you can use delegates. But from your sample, I can see that it's easier than that. But worth mentioning.

Comment: Is there any possible way to create a sample code ? Thanks

Comment: Here is my app: https://github.com/lauracalinoiu/MaintainStreak/tree/master/MaintainStreak    MainVC contains delegates, see `viewWillAppear`. Every vc is a delegate for the other one.

Answer (score 0):

@Mc.Lover U can use a UITableview for base view and then take one tableview cell for Library and one collection view cell for Recently added item.
Now In cellForRoAatIndexPath load first tableview cell for section 0 and second collection view cell for section 1.